# LDAP socket keep-alive

Tags: networking, tcp, ldap, openldap, keep-alive

We are using OpenLDAP client library to conect to an LDAP server. The problem is that if there is no activity for some time, server (or firewall in the middle) drops TCP connection.

Our current implementation of "keep-alive" just does search for baseDN from time to time - any better ideas ?

Comment: C++ but it seems that bindings to OpenLDAP are very similar for most languages

Comment: Why? You shouldn't keep LDAP connections open.

Comment: Since reopening of a connection can take a long time - with authentication, clustered servers etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only alternative seems to be reconnect:

```
ldap_set_option( ld, LDAP_OPT_RECONNECT, LDAP_OPT_ON );
```

Answer (score 2):

`LDAP_OPT_RECONNECT` is not available in OpenLdap

Answer (score 2):

LDAP Abandon might work:

```
if (ldap_abandon(ld, 0, sctrls, cctrls) != LDAP_SUCCESS)
    {
       /* handle ldap error */
    };
```

There was a discussion about this on the OpenLDAP mailing list:

http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-devel/200905/msg00008.html

In Brief:
The abandon request sends a message to the server, however the server does not send a response back to the client for abandon requests. Zero is not a valid MSGID for LDAP requests.  Since the zero is an invalid MSGID and the server does not respond to abandon requests, in theory the server will ignore an abandon request for msgid zero.  This would provide activity upon the TCP socket, preventing the firewall from dropping the connection.

See:

- RFC 4511, Section 4.11: Abandon Operation
- RFC 4511, Section 4.1.1.1: MessageID

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511